parquet file is Column-based format, if I want to query the data, should I also load them into Column-based format table?
parquet file is Column-based format, if I want to query the data, should I also load them into Column-based format table? If I load them into SQL table or Oracle, is it kind of waste of parquet file's column-based feature? I mainly use the data for join and aggregation for BI reports.
thanks
I do not have tried to load parquet into a column-based database. so I have not tired to compare the performance between a row-based and column-based database.
